# List manager doesn't show contact in manual subscription

Tags: sitecore-client, xconnect

I have a question about List manager since I stuck here for a week and half. I have made xConnect to save contacts into xDB. I checked that there are saved contacts in SQL Management, which I already made them through my code(without interaction). But when I check this data into list manager, I could not see any contacts. 
At this moment, To test if it is injected properly, I saved a contact in contact list manually through list manager in sitecore panel(UI). Then I can see it is displayed "Manual Subscriptions | **0**" *in Included lists and sources*. Even though there is "Manual subscriptions" since I added a contact, the Recipients is just 0 now. (Add: there are contacts list and segmented list in only **Recently created lists** )

As solving this problem, I did rebuild index through indexing manager, and change value of IndexAnonymousContactData as **true** in sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml. but it is not working.

By digging this problem, I realized that I should code with interaction (I realized that it is for EXM. not for list manager). However, I was wondering if it is right behavior not to be shown contact in sitecore when I add it manually.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How you are saving contacts into List Manager? and are you using Save Contact on form submission?

Comment: I made a contact manager object, then used that 2 lines of code. manager.SaveAndReleaseInSharedSessionState, manager.SaveContactToCollectionDb after adding subscriptions and client.submit

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced this many times (specifically in my dev instance).

List Manager in Sitecore 9 displays data from 'xDB' Solr index (with previous versions of Sitecore, it was separate list index). It won't show the Contact until it gets indexed even though the Contact has been added to xConnect Collection database. Hence you need to make sure that your recently added Contact (either manually or automated) has been indexed as well. You can verify this from the Solr Console (either the last updated timestamp of your _xDB index or the existence of Contact ID taken from xConnect database).
In case it is not indexed, you may force trigger the index using the following command on Command Prompt:

```
<xConnect Collection Search service root>\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\XConnectSearchIndexer -rr
```

where rr is the request rebuild (also refer: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/rebuild-the-xdb-index-in-solr.html)

Generally, XConnectSearchIndexer is added as a windows service by your xConnect installation script. This service is responsible to trigger the xDB index and keep it in sync. But you can use the above mentioned force trigger command in case of any glitch with this service. Run it and it should definitely display the Contact under List Manager. Hope it helps!

Comment: the thing is that list manager api was blocked for the performance so that it was working on the another server. Thank you for your comment that I could study more in detail